# Is there a way to add a tweet button that doesn't link back to the referring page?

Tags: twitter

I am trying to add a button to a page to tweet a message, but I don't want it to link back to the referring page.

For example:  [tweet](http://twitter.com/share?text=Some%20text%20goes%20here) adds a t.co link to the end of the tweet that points at the referring page.

Does anyone know of a way to keep that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

http://twitter.com/?status=Your%20text%20goes%20here

Comment: Nice, but that only works if they are already signed in.  If they aren't signed in the status disappears after they do.